# Force selection attribute for dijit.form.ComboBox

Tags: javascript, dojo

Does `dijit.form.ComboBox` has `forceSelection` attribute (or similar, like in `p:autoComplete` in PrimeFaces), that will allow only the values from the store to be selected?

I'd expect, if user types something, that's not in the store, the widget should be either cleared or returned to the previous value.

Is there anything like that for `ComboBox`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would want to try the widget dijit.form.FilteringSelect. Filtering Select is very similar to ComboBox, the main difference being that filtering select will throw a validation warning / error if what is selected is not from the dropdown. You can refer to more details in  http://kennethfranqueiro.com/2010/06/combobox-vs-filteringselect/